# Mocked operation performance in Azure API Management

Tags: azure-api-management

I have an Azure API Management API composed of only mocked operations. Most, like the bottom of the attached image, run in the tenths of a ms. However, one that is test/plain coming in and returns application/json typically runs in tens of seconds (top of image). I find this using developer console or calling from Logic Apps. My case has 1.7K coming in, the returned JSON is large-ish at 26K.

Still this great amount of response time seems excessive. Might there be an explanation for it?

My Representation example returned by the mock

```
{
"FunctionalGroup": {
    "TransactionSet": {
        "@controlNumber": "270001",
        "Area": [
            {
                "Segment": [
                    {
                        "@id": "BEG",
                        "Element": [
                            {
                                "@pos": "1",
                                "#text": "00"
                            },
                            {
                                "@pos": "2",
                                "#text": "SA"
                            },
                            {
                                "@pos": "3",
                                "#text": "86816853"
                            },
                            {
                                "@pos": "5",
                                "@date": "2015-04-09",
                                "#text": "20150409"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "@id": "REF",
                        "Element": [
                            {
                                "@pos": "1",
                                "#text": "DP"
                            },
                            {
                                "@pos": "2",
                                "#text": "16"
                            },
                            {
                                "@pos": "3",
                                "#text": "DEPARTMENTA"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "SegmentLoop": [
                    {
                        "@id": "N9",
                        "@name": "N9",
                        "Segment": [
                            {
                                "@id": "N9",
                                "Element": [
                                    {
                                        "@pos": "1",
                                        "#text": "ST"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "@pos": "2",
                                        "#text": "001"
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "@id": "DTM",
                                "Element": [
                                    {
                                        "@pos": "1",
                                        "#text": "010"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "@pos": "2",
                                        "@date": "2015-04-12",
                                        "#text": "20150412"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "@pos": "3",
                                        "@time": "00:00:00",
                                        "#text": "0000"
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "@id": "DTM",
                                "Element": [
                                    {
                                        "@pos": "1",
                                        "#text": "002"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "@pos": "2",
                                        "@date": "2015-04-12",
                                        "#text": "20150412"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "@pos": "3",
                                        "@time": "12:34:34",
                                        "#text": "123456"
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "@id": "DTM",
                                "Element": [
                                    {
                                        "@pos": "1",
                                        "#text": "001"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "@pos": "2",
                                        "@date": "2015-04-30",
                                        "#text": "20150430"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "@pos": "3",
                                        "@time": "12:34:34.789",
                                        "#text": "123456789"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "@id": "N1",
                        "@name": "N1",
                        "Segment": [
                            {
                                "@id": "N1",
                                "Element": [
                                    {
                                        "@pos": "1",
                                        "#text": "ST"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "@pos": "2",
                                        "#text": "COMPANY INC."
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "@pos": "3",
                                        "#text": "92"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "@pos": "4",
                                        "#text": "001"
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "@id": "N3",
                                "Element": [
                                    {
                                        "@pos": "1",
                                        "#text": "123 main street"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "@pos": "2",
                                        "#text": "PH:(644)123-4567"
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "@id": "N4",
                                "Element": [
                                    {
                                        "@pos": "1",
                                        "#text": "Elk Grove Village"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "@pos": "2",
                                        "#text": "IL"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "@pos": "3",
                                        "#text": "6007"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "@pos": "4",
                                        "#text": "US"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "@id": "N1",
                        "@name": "N1",
                        "Segment": [
                            {
                                "@id": "N1",
                                "Element": [
                                    {
                                        "@pos": "1",
                                        "#text": "SF"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "@pos": "2",
                                        "#text": "EDGE ENTERPRISES"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "@pos": "3",
                                        "#text": "92"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "@pos": "4",
                                        "#text": "99999"
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "@id": "N3",
                                "Element": [
                                    {
                                        "@pos": "1",
                                        "#text": "2645 W. Coast Highway"
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "@id": "N4",
                                "Element": [
                                    {
                                        "@pos": "1",
                                        "#text": "Silicon Valley"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "@pos": "2",
                                        "#text": "CA"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "@pos": "3",
                                        "#text": "56874"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "@pos": "4",
                                        "#text": "US"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "SegmentLoop": [
                    {
                        "@id": "PO1",
                        "@name": "PO1",
                        "Segment": [
                            {
                                "@id": "PO1",
                                "Element": [
                                    {
                                        "@pos": "1",
                                        "#text": "1"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "@pos": "2",
                                        "#text": "96"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "@pos": "3",
                                        "#text": "EA"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "@pos": "4",
                                        "#text": "2.05"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "@pos": "6",
                                        "#text": "BP"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "@pos": "7",
                                        "#text": "HB-Natural Adult Bat"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ],
                        "SegmentLoop": [
                            {
                                "@id": "PID",
                                "@name": "PID",
                                "Segment": [
                                    {
                                        "@id": "PID",
                                        "Element": [
                                            {
                                                "@pos": "1",
                                                "#text": "F"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "@pos": "5",
                                                "#text": "DESCRIPTION"
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "SegmentLoop": [
                    {
                        "@id": "CTT",
                        "@name": "CTT",
                        "Segment": [
                            {
                                "@id": "CTT",
                                "Element": [
                                    {
                                        "@pos": "1",
                                        "#text": "6"
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "@id": "AMT",
                                "Element": [
                                    {
                                        "@pos": "1",
                                        "#text": "TT"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "@pos": "2",
                                        "@number": "1000.00",
                                        "#text": "100000"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

}

My Policy in effect for the relevant API op

```
<policies>
<inbound>
    <!--base: Begin Global scope-->
    <!-- PC-1404 -->
    <set-query-parameter name="subscription-key" exists-action="delete" />
    <!--base: End Global scope-->
</inbound>
<backend>
    <!--base: Begin Global scope-->
    <forward-request />
    <!--base: End Global scope-->
</backend>
<outbound>
    <mock-response status-code="200" content-type="application/json" />
</outbound>
<on-error>
    <!--base: Begin Global scope-->
    <!-- By placing policy statements in the on-error section you can review the error by 
    using the context.LastError property, inspect and customize the error response using the 
    set-body policy, and configure what happens if an error occurs. 
    There are error codes for built-in steps and for errors that may occur during the processing of 
    policy statements. 
    For more information, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt629506.aspx
    statements to be applied if there is an error condition go here -->
    <!-- for CORS support to Office Add-In to detect subscription key errors, etc. PLEX-JIRA: PC-725 TSCH 8/16/16 -->
    <set-header name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" exists-action="override">
        <value>*</value>
    </set-header>
    <!--base: End Global scope-->
</on-error>
```

Comment: also, the mocked op takes seconds whether it is first and I have tried multiple different mocked ops first, each other mocked op is tenths of an ms whether it is first or not. I am convinced it is specific to this mocked op

Comment: If you run this request from within the portal, do you see the same slow speed?  Does the trace give any hint as to where the delay is coming from?

Comment: Also, if you move mock-response policy to the inbound section, does the performance improve?

Comment: Hi @DarrelMiller

Yes, I saw the same delay within portal, which allowed me to exclude Logic Apps. The trace there did show the delay in the backend section (I like how the trace in Dev Portal console has a link to each section), so that prompted me to move the mock policy to the inbound section, which resolved the delay. (I either missed your comment here, or added that as my answer before your comment? Either way, I haven't checked my Stack Overflow inbox until this morning...)

Answer (score 2):

I found I needed to move the mock call up to the inbound section. It was the forward to back end (I actually don't have a backend figured that was taking the time). The new op policy is

```
<policies>
<inbound>
    <mock-response status-code="200" content-type="application/json" />
    <base />
</inbound>
<backend>
    <base />
</backend>
<outbound>
    <base />
</outbound>
<on-error>
    <base />
</on-error>
```

Comment: I will ask the team why you might want to put it anywhere other than the inbound.  If there isn't any reason, we should update the docs.

Comment: Thanks, @DarrelMiller - if not only the docs, the UI, too. The UI does complain for other policy elements when placed inappropriately.

Comment: We do explicitly allow it other places.  I'm just not sure why we do.